# inno setup checkbox with multiple versions and install directories

Tags: installation, inno-setup, vst

I have a software that has 4 different versions. I need to set the Inno Setup installer with 4 checkbox and 4 different target directory locations. For example;

- **VST 32 bit:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Vstplugins
- **VST 64 bit:** C:\Program Files\Vstplugins
- **AAX 32 bit:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Avid\Audio\Plug-Ins
- **AAX 64 bit:** C:\Program Files\Common Files\Avid\Audio\Plug-Ins

Is it possible?

Comment: *“can loacate the installation directory individually for each one”* - can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Also, do you want to allow a user to install multiple options side by side, by running the installer again with a different selection? Should these show as separate entries in control panel/settings app?

Comment: It sould be something like this: https://image.ibb.co/cUvyNo/dnmmmmmm.jpg   Don't bother directory pats, it's ust an example.  The idea is this but it's no problem if we can solve this situation with different ways

Comment: Thank you so much  for helping Martin. Adding multiple directories is ok now. But I've couldn't see checkboxes for enabling/disabling for each destination folder.

Comment: Now that you know how to implement multiple directories, please edit your question to narrow it down to the “checkboxes”. Your current question is too broad for SO anyway.

Comment: It would help, if you show us how will you implement the multiple directories. As the check box solution depends on that.